# 1-Parametric Transformation Group of a Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $$y=x^r F(y/x)$$  $r$ being a real parameter, be a first order Ordinary Differential Equation (ODE). What is its 1-parametric group allowing to reduce it to a differential equation in separated variables? This situation arises for instance, while considering the ODE $$M dx + N dy = 0$$ when $M$ and $N$ are homogeneous functions of $x$ and $y$ but of different degrees.